# disable pagination if data less then number in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, pagination, codeigniter-3

i want to disable pagination if data less then 5.

i have tried many solution in internet, but i dont know pagination still appeared. the data in database just 2.

here's my controller

```
public function index(){
        //$data['result'] = $this->MTransaksi->getlist("B");
        $data['kembali'] = true;
        $jumlah_data = $this->MTransaksi->jumlah_data();

        echo $jumlah_data;
        //example pagination
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/Kembali/index/';
        if(($config['total_rows'] = $jumlah_data) > 5){
            $config['per_page'] = 5;
            $from = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data['result'] = $this->MTransaksi->data($config['per_page'], $from);
        }else{
            $data['result'] = $this->MTransaksi->getlist("B");
        }
        $this->load->view('kembali', $data);
    }
```

here's my model

```
//example pagination
    public function data($number, $offset){
        $status = 'B';
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('status', $status);
        $this->db->join('pelanggan', 'transaksi.id_pelanggan = pelanggan.id_pelanggan');
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table, $number, $offset);
        //return $query = $this->db->get($this->table, $number, $offset)->result();
        return $query->result();
    }

    //example pagination
    public function jumlah_data(){
        $status = 'K';
        $this->db->select('*');
        //$this->db->from('transaksi');
        $this->db->where('status', $status);
        $this->db->join('pelanggan', 'transaksi.id_pelanggan = pelanggan.id_pelanggan');
        // $query = $this->db->get();
        // return $query->num_rows();
        return $this->db->count_all($this->table);
    }
```

and last this is my view

```
<?php if($result) : ?>
    <?php //print_r($result) ?>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>No. Kendaraan</th>
                <th>Nama Peminjam</th>
                <th>Tanggal Pinjam</th>
                <th>Tanggal Kembali</th>
                <th>Aksi</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php $i = $this->uri->segment('3') + 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($result as $row) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $i ?>.</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->nomor_kendaraan?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->nama_pelanggan ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->tanggal_pinjam ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->tanggal_kembali ?></td>
                    <td> <a href="<?php echo site_url()?>/Kembali/kembalikan/<?php echo $row->id_transaksi ?>">Kembalikan</a> </td>
                </tr>
                <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?></p>
<?php else :?>
    Tidak ada data
<?php endif ?>
```

if you see my controller. i create **echo** to see the number. when i see on the view it showed 15. but in table just 2 data.

i just want to hide pagination if data less then 5.

Comment: the query is different in the two queries, so you won't get good results either. 
Your first query status="K" (15 rows) and then status="B" (2) rows..

Comment: omg. i forgot about it. status 'K' should be write status 'B'. thanks